# output literal html code in a normal paragraph in markdown?

Tags: markdown

I have a problem in markdown writing.If I want to write a `<div>` tag in a normal paragraph not in code blocks or code span,how do I write it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put `div` elements inside `p`, because the `p` element *"cannot contain block-level elements (including `p` itself)."*

Read more about it here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Can you explain why you need to do this? I think your problem may be solved in other way.

Answer (score 0):

As the [rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.
>
> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements — e.g. `<div>`, `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. — must be separated from surrounding content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the block should not be indented with tabs or spaces. Markdown is smart enough not to add extra (unwanted) `<p>` tags around HTML block-level tags.

For example:

```
Some Markdown text.

<div>
    Some content in a div...
<div>

Some more Markdown text.
```